# Automating custom field creation in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, redmine

I want to write a plugin for redmine that will depend on quite a few [custom fields](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/1/RedmineCustomFields), so I would like to create the custom fields automatically. Ideally within the plugin code, or if not by a script I can run when I install the plugin - I really don't want to have to create 10+ fields through the web interface when I set this up, especially when one is a list with quite a few values.

Can anyone tell me if there are standard ways of doing this?

Also is there a good way to export the custom fields from an existing installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use migrate scripts. Put your scripts into `#{PLUGIN_ROOT}/db/migrate` and call `.create` there. The Redmine sources contain many similar scripts.

For example, the script can have a name: `001_populate_custom_fields.rb`.

Content:

```
class PopulateCustomFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        CustomField.create ...
    end
    def self.down
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the API for CustomField.create? i need to add a custom field to my issue list, but can't seem to find any way to directly do this

Comment: Anyone knows where can we find the API of CustomField.create?

Answer (score 1):

As Andriy Lesyuk answered, put your script under `#{PLUGIN_ROOT}/db/migrate` and test it by using the command for installing/uninstalling your plugin.

For installing the plugin use the command:

```
rake redmine:plugins:migrate
```

and for uninstalling it:

```
rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=<your plugin name> VERSION=0
```

Check the official [documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugins) for further details.

For example, the script `001_populate_custom_fields.rb` could be something like:

```
class PopulateCustomFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # method called when installing the plugin
  def self.up
    if CustomField.find_by_name('A New Custom Field').nil?
      CustomField.create(name: 'A New Custom Field', field_format: 'text')
    end
  end

  # method called when uninstalling the plugin
  def self.down
    CustomField.find_by_name('A New Custom Field').delete unless CustomField.find_by_name('A New Custom Field').nil?
  end
end
```

This will create/remove the custom field "A New Custom Field" of type "text", after checking its existence from the redmine database table custom_fields.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer rather than actual one. This one has way more information and way more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Custom fields essentially are pretty much implemented as a resource (however there is no resource route for custom_fields). I don't see a reason why you shouldn't be able to just use CustomField.create/new to create the fields your plugin needs. Likewise you should be able to just use find() to get all existing custom fields.
However, I have to say that I have never done this before and don't know if this is the standard way. But, off the hand, I can't see anything wrong with doing it this way.